# How to change check box to light mode. Ext version 7.6

Tags: extjs

The check boxes from Ext.js are in dark mode. How do you change them to light mode? When we were in 6.5 they were all in light mode. This problem started occurring as soon as we upgraded to 7.6.[7.6 checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDDcz.jpg)

We tried changing the theme but it didn't seem to help much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.